# How can I let a div fill 100% width if no other elements are beside it?

Tags: html, css

I have simple markup like this (a tab menu):

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="tab1"></div>
   <div class="tab2"></div>
   <div class="tab3"></div>
</div>
```

That is the case when all elements have an equal width of 33% to fill 100% of the container.

Is it possible to apply a general CSS rule for all containers that automatically detects if, for example, there are only 1 other container or none? And then adjusts the width of the tabs? ("Strech-To-Fit")

Perhaps something with `min-width` or `max-width`?

Comment: Just an FYI, three elements with 33% width each will add to 99%, not 100%.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Depending on [what browsers you need to support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), you may be able to use flexbox:

```js
$('.tab').click(function() {
  $(this).css('display', 'none');
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.tab {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<p>Click a tab to remove it</p>
<div class="container">
   <div class="tab">Tab 1</div>
   <div class="tab">Tab 2</div>
   <div class="tab">Tab 3</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @mangotasche See https://demos.scotch.io/visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-flexbox-playground/demos/ (Set the width slider to 100% and play with removing/adding children)

Comment: Very clever! Just remember to check out `flex`'s [support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm. I did not yet know about flex :)

Comment: With flexbox you shouldn't need to use jQuery.

Comment: @TylerH I believe that jQuery was just used for the hide-on-click for demonstration reasons, it does not affect the solution at all.

Comment: @Drew Kennedy: There's nothing clever about this - it's practically the simplest example of flexbox there is. But that does speak volumes about how powerful flexbox can be.

Comment: @Kroltan Hence the "no need for jQuery"

Comment: @TylerH Oh pardon me, I interpreted your comment as saying "you shouldn't need to use jQuery" as if the answerer had suggested flexbox is provided by jQuery. Sorry for misunderstanding, English is not my first language and sometimes I still get some things wrong. :)

Comment: @Kroltan No worries :-) it was a pretty abrupt statement anyway!

Answer (score 16):

You mean like flexbox?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
[class*="tab"] {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab1"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="tab1"></div>
  <div class="tab2"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="tab1"></div>
  <div class="tab2"></div>
  <div class="tab3"></div>
</div>
```

Or CSS Tables

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
[class*="tab"] {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab1"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="tab1"></div>
  <div class="tab2"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="tab1"></div>
  <div class="tab2"></div>
  <div class="tab3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Upvoted for the table one as it is [more supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=table)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `display:table` and `display:table-cell` see below code

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="tab">Tab 1</div>
   <div class="tab">Tab 2</div>
   <div class="tab">Tab 3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: table;
  width:100%;
}

.tab {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 5px;
}
```