# How do I make multiple divs arrange horizontally with equal width?

Tags: html, css

I want two, three or more divs arranged horizontally, then each width will fill all the available space.  For example with two divs, they will each take up half the space, with three divs they will take up 1/3 the space, and so on.

I tried using display inline-block, and can get the divs to arrange side by side, but how do you make them fill available width of parent container?

EDIT:  Preferably without display flex method (I'm not sure if its compatible with IE11 fully)

```css
.container{
  border: solid 1px green;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;


}
.button{
  display:inline-block;
  border: solid 1px black;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="button ">
div1
</div>
<div class="button ">
div2
</div>
<div class="button ">
div3
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know bootstrap ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325371/how-can-i-let-a-div-fill-100-width-if-no-other-elements-are-beside-it/35325430#35325430

Comment: FYI, SO has its own snippet mechanism these days.  You can get at it with the icon above the editing window that looks like a document with `<>` on it.

Comment: @zwol so like a version of jsfiddle but embedded in SO?

Comment: @sjs That's exactly what it is.  I edited your question to use it.

Comment: `flex-grow` works fine in IE11: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37039546/3597276

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `display: table` in the container and `display: table-cell` on buttons.

```css
.container{
  border: solid 1px green;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
display: table;
width: 100%;

}
.button{
  display: table-cell;
  border: solid 1px black;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="button ">
div1
</div>
<div class="button ">
div2
</div>
<div class="button ">
div3
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is the best non-flexbox solution.

Answer (score 5):

This is trivial with [flexbox](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/) layout:

```css
.container{
  border: solid 1px green;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
}
.button{
  display:inline-block;
  border: solid 1px black;
  height: 20px;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="button ">
div1
</div>
<div class="button ">
div2
</div>
<div class="button ">
div3
</div>
</div>
```

All I did was add the `display:flex` and `flex:1` properties to `container` and `button` respectively.

[Flexbox is very widely supported nowadays](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), but you might want to avoid it if you care about IE (up to and including version 11) or older Android.  Unfortunately, *without* flexbox, what you want to do is much more difficult.  I will let someone else write a non-flexbox answer.

Comment: Thanks, I was concerned that IE11 would barf it up since I found a lot of links online saying its buggy.

Comment: @sjs if you manage to avoid all the bugs [listed here](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs), a flexbox will look fine in IE11.

Comment: Keep in mind that in a *flex formatting context*, the `display` property on flex children is ignored / overridden. There's no point in using `display: inline-block`, as you have in your code.

Comment: @Michael_B I left it in to underscore the minimal changes from the OP's code.